# prevent PHP object from auto-casting

Tags: php, object, casting

```
 class Foo 
{
    public $var ;

    function __construct($value) 
    {
         $this->var = $value ;
    }
}
$myFoo = new Foo('hello');
echo $myFoo->var . '<br>' ; // output : hello
// Question : how  can I prevent another programer from accidentaly doing the following
$myFoo = 4 ;
echo $myFoo ; // output : 4
```

my question is in the comment // Question :...

I would like my coworkers being able to assign values to $myFoo use only $myFoo->var (or whatever public mutators are available in the class Foo)

thank you

**EDIT :**
with all respect to the users who claim it is not possible, SPL_Types PECL extention was able to achieve that (to a certain degree) see e.g http://php.net/manual/en/class.splint.php or http://blog.felixdv.com/2008/01/09/spl_types-in-php-and-strong-typing/

Comment: You can't, but you can check the variable type when you need to use it and throw an exception/error if it is not what you expect it to be.

You are not really recasting in your example, you are assigning a new value to a variable.

Comment: You can not do it. It can only be done if you leave using `=` operator.

Comment: Either you write your own IDE, or you just be sure to work with smart people.

Comment: About SPL managing to do this... From the example: `$int = new SplInt(94);`. What's to keep the programmer from writing `$int = new SplInt(1234);` after? Either way, this is an extension that changes the behavior of the language to add something like type safety. First, it *changes* the language, this cannot be done within the language itself. Second, it does not provide constants. And third, the programmer needs to use this explicitly, you cannot force him to. Again, you cannot force the value assigned to a variable to be constant while creating the value (this is true for all languages).

Comment: SPL_Types is an extension to the PHP language. It is **experimental**. And PHP is bad enough without such crazy typing mechanism. Use Java/Tomcat or similar if you want strong typing.

Comment: (to be more explicit, a *variable* will always be re-assignable regardless of what its value is, and this is true in all programming languages... to prevent this, the programmer must do it explicitly, you cannot force it)

Comment: @rid but then you are forced to use public constructor/mutator which is what I'm aiming for, and of course keep the variable type the same as well.anyways I still think your answer below about type hinting in the function arguments a viable option.

Comment: @exTrace101, sure, if all you want is to keep consistency, but not force the programmer to make his variables constant, there are many things you can do, for example use type hinted accessors and methods. This way, you ensure that your methods always receive the correct type, thus forcing the programmer to supply the correct type by whatever means, whether or not he's using constants or variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in any weakly typed language. If you have functions that take this variable as an argument, you can use type hinting in PHP, but otherwise you cannot prevent people from re-assigning their variables.

This is true to an extent even for strongly typed languages. If a programmer creates two instances of a class, there is no mechanism to prevent them from assigning a different instance to a variable of the same type.

The only way this can happen is if the programmer explicitly uses *constants* instead of *variables* (such as using things like `final` in Java, or `val` in Scala, etc), but, either way, you have no control over it in any language.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it provides a rather practical solution, after lots of googling the more correct answer seems to me is to write my own extension but that would be well...less practical :-) thank you

Comment: @exTrace101, indeed. This is what the language provides. If you want to change the language to make it a different language, you can write an extension for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent changing the type within the class, but if you make it protected or private and then add a setVariable() method (where Variable is your variable name) you can control the input. Something like:

```
class myClass {
    protected $integer = 0;
    public function setInteger($new_value)
    {
        if (!is_int($new_value)) {
             throw new RuntimeException('Cannot assign non-integer value to myClass::$integer');
        }
        $this->integer = $new_value;
    }
    public function getInteger()
    {
        return $this->integer;
    }
}

// Now, outside of the class, the $integer property can only be changed using setInteger()
$class = new myClass;
$class->setInteger('dog'); // Uncaught Runtime exception ...
$class->setInteger(5);
echo $class->getInteger(); // 5
```

An alternative version of that function would accept string numbers and convert them to integers:

```
    public function setInteger($new_value)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($new_value)) {
             throw new RuntimeException('Cannot assign non-integer value to myClass::$integer');
        }
        $this->integer = (int) $new_value;
    }
$class->setInteger('5'); // 5
```

Comment: if you add $class = 'hello' ; after $class->setInteger(); your $class object is all of the sudden a string

Comment: @exTrace101, which is true for all weakly typed languages. An IDE might warn you, but the language does not. The fact that you can re-assign any value to a variable is a feature of weakly typed languages, just as the opposite is a feature of strongly typed languages. The experimental SPL_Types extension adds some strong typing features to PHP, which is a weakly typed language.

Comment: @exTrace101 That's PHP, which was not made for strong types